# Is there a way to let a pictures add-on navigate across page breaks?

Tags: xbmc, kodi

I am currently trying to create a Kodi add-on that provides pictures to the user. From what I understand from the Kodi programming instructions this is done by providing a set of links with a title from a Python script.

The pictures I want to provide are online, i.e. I need to fetch the URL and the title for each picture via an API. Since the total number of pictures is somewhat above 1000 and I can only get the title for each picture with a separate request, I would like to limit the number of entries I display and provide the user with paging as I have seen several other add-ons do.

However, the downside to this approach seems to be that when you are looking at a picture and navigating via the right/left arrow keys to next/previous picture, Kodi will not be able to load the next page. Instead, it will only cycle through pictures on the current page.

Is there a way to avoid this, i.e. to tell Kodi to load the next page once it reaches the end of the current page?